# "'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument" flutter error

Tags: flutter

How to solve this error?

**The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. (Documentation)  Try adding the required argument.**

**error**

[image]

```
Future<void> onJoin() async {
    // update input validation
    setState(() {
      _channelController.text.isEmpty
          ? _validateError = true
          : _validateError = false;
    });
    if (_channelController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _handleCameraAndMic(Permission.camera);
      await _handleCameraAndMic(Permission.microphone);
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => VideoCall(
            channelName: _channelController.text,
            role: _role,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

**class VideoCall**

```
class VideoCall extends StatefulWidget {
  final String channelName;
  final ClientRole role;
  const VideoCall({Key key, required this.channelName, required this.role})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoCallState createState() => _VideoCallState();
}

class _VideoCallState extends State<VideoCall> {
  final _users = <int>[];
  final _infoStrings = <String>[];
  bool muted = false;
  late RtcEngine _engine;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // clear users
    _users.clear();
    // destroy sdk
    _engine.leaveChannel();
    _engine.destroy();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // initialize agora sdk
    initialize();
  }
```

this is the videoCall class in there no any error shows.

when add "key" show this
[image]

When remove required property from key in video call class

[image]

show this error

Comment: Add key to `VideoCall` object.

Comment: can you show your VIdeoCall class?

Comment: sure i will update the question

Comment: @KasymbekR.Tashbaev when add that show "The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'." this error.I will add that image in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `VideoCall` class, `key` property set as a `required`, change it to `optional`:

```
class VideoCall extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? channelName;
  final ClientRole? role;
  const VideoCall({Key? key, this.channelName, this.role})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoCallState createState() => _VideoCallState();
}
```

Comment: bro thanks for your reply. I change remove "?"  from "channelName" and " ClientRole" in video call class. and aslo like as your code i change that in key  property then show this error. I will update the question

Comment: I updated the question bro and i added the new code

Comment: My mistake, I forgot add `?` to key, I updated my answer.

Comment: Now no any errors show thank you bro