# "The named parameter 'channelId' is required, but there's no corresponding argument." Flutter error how to solve?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io, agora-implementation

I tried to built video call using agora 5. But "RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView" show some error.I couldn't understand what's the reason for this.

**error**

[image]

**imports**

```
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_local_view.dart' as RtcLocalView;
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_remote_view.dart' as RtcRemoteView;
```

[image]

**code**

```
     class VideoCall extends StatefulWidget {
  final String channelName;
  final ClientRole role;

  const VideoCall({Key? key, required this.channelName, required this.role})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoCallState createState() => _VideoCallState();
}

class _VideoCallState extends State<VideoCall> {
  final _users = <int>[];
  final _infoStrings = <String>[];
  bool muted = false;
  RtcEngine? _engine;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // clear users
    _users.clear();
    // destroy sdk
    _engine?.leaveChannel();
    _engine?.destroy();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // initialize agora sdk
    initialize();
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    if (APP_ID.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _infoStrings.add(
          'APP_ID missing, please provide your APP_ID in settings.dart',
        );
        _infoStrings.add('Agora Engine is not starting');
      });
      return;
    }

    await _initAgoraRtcEngine();
    _addAgoraEventHandlers();
    await _engine?.enableWebSdkInteroperability(true);
    VideoEncoderConfiguration configuration = VideoEncoderConfiguration();
    configuration.dimensions = const VideoDimensions(); //(1920,1080)
    await _engine?.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(configuration);
    await _engine?.joinChannel(Token, widget.channelName, null!, 0);
  }

  Future<void> _initAgoraRtcEngine() async {
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(APP_ID);
    await _engine?.enableVideo();
    await _engine?.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    await _engine?.setClientRole(widget.role);
  }

  void _addAgoraEventHandlers() {
    _engine?.setEventHandler(RtcEngineEventHandler(error: (code) {
      setState(() {
        final info = 'onError: $code';
        _infoStrings.add(info);
      });
    }, joinChannelSuccess: (channel, uid, elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        final info = 'onJoinChannel: $channel, uid: $uid';
        _infoStrings.add(info);
      });
    }, leaveChannel: (stats) {
      setState(() {
        _infoStrings.add('onLeaveChannel');
        _users.clear();
      });
    }, userJoined: (uid, elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        final info = 'userJoined: $uid';
        _infoStrings.add(info);
        _users.add(uid);
      });
    }, userOffline: (uid, elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        final info = 'userOffline: $uid';
        _infoStrings.add(info);
        _users.remove(uid);
      });
    }, firstRemoteVideoFrame: (uid, width, height, elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        final info = 'firstRemoteVideo: $uid ${width}x $height';
        _infoStrings.add(info);
      });
    }));
  }

  List<Widget> _getRenderViews() {
    final List<StatefulWidget> list = [];
    if (widget.role == ClientRole.Broadcaster) {
      list.add(RtcLocalView.SurfaceView());
    }
    _users.forEach((int uid) => list.add(RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(uid: uid)));
    return list;
  }
add(RtcLocalView.SurfaceView());
        }
        _users.forEach((int uid) => list.add(RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(uid: uid)));
        return list;
      }
```

**pubspec.yaml file packages**

[image]

How to solve this "The named parameter 'channelId' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. (Documentation)  Try adding the required argument" error?

Comment: This is just another case of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74794058/).  You're calling a function that has a required named argument, but you aren't providing that argument.  Either call the function and provide that argument or, if you control the function you're calling, make the argument optional.

Comment: I couldn't get it bro

Comment: Do you understand what [named parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters) are?

Comment: So what are you confused about?  You need to pass a `channelId` argument, as the error message says.  If you don't understand *what value* to pass, then that would be a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide `channelid` to `SurfaceView` see the example in the official package [site](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine/example)